# LIFT: preventing orphaned records when destroying an object

Tags: scala, record, lift

i am currently learning the lift framework, and have a question regarding persistence in associated records.

if i had a model, say, artist.
i also have a model called album, and one called track.
an artist can have many albums, which have many tracks.

is there a way in the model to set up the dependency such that when i deleted an artist, all of their albums, and in turn, all of their tracks were deleted?

i am planning on using record with mongodb.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Lift doesn't have any central or official database wrapper. You can use any you want. For example, I use pure squeryl.

If you're talking about record-squeryl -- then the main documentation page shows an example of one-to-many relation: https://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/liftweb/Squeryl

If you're talking about mongodb+record -- then I see a page like this https://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/liftweb/MongoDB  that can suit you.

Also not that there is also Rogue around, and that questions are much more quicker answered if you use the mailing list https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/liftweb . AFAIK, it's the main way to ask questions about Lift.